# REGEX / Dialogflow / Formatt Entity

Tags: python, regex, format, expression, dialogflow-es

My goal is to create an entity within Dialogflow called 'Order-ID'

I would like dialogflow to understand/passback a reference value for this Order-ID regardless if the user enters it correctly or incorrectly.

Correct example: 123-1234567-1234567
Incorrect example: 12312345671234567
Incorrect example: My order # is 12312345671234567

Can I achieve this with RegEx in dialogflow?

Comment: did you solve that? I also faced with auto-unchecking, so weird it is

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

arrs = [
    '1231234567-1234567',
    '123-12345671234567',
    '-123-1234567-1234567',
    '12312345671234567',
    '123-1234567-1234567',
]

for t in arrs:
    print(t,' =>',end=' ')
    if re.match(r'\d{3}\-\d{7}\-\d{7}',t):
        print('Correct')
    else:
        print('Something is wrong!')
```

Result:

```
1231234567-1234567  => Something is wrong!
123-12345671234567  => Something is wrong!
-123-1234567-1234567  => Something is wrong!
12312345671234567  => Something is wrong!
123-1234567-1234567  => Correct
```

Comment: Thanks, Ano0ther0ne.  Is there a way to achieve this simply through regex?

Comment: this is exactly regex : r'\d{3}\-\d{7}\-\d{7}'
If my answer useful for u -- put your finger up. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use DialogFlow feature. It provides regex for entities.

[image]

For more, you can check [official document](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-regexp)

Comment: But how to set it up ? When I check regexp entity and enter a one ex: \A[0-9A-Za-z]{5,}\z
and then save it, it auto uncheck.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this regex `\A([1-9]{3}-[1-9]{7}-[1-9]{7})\z`. Dialogflow uses re2 regex format. you can visit https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax for reference.